# "70053" vulnerable environment detected the app will be closed - android 12

Tags: android, android-12

We have a Real Money Gaming (RMG) app on Android which contains a couple of games that run on Unity.

I have a pixel device and I just upgraded to Android 12 provided by Google as a system update.

Now, whenever I'm opening my app, it shows the following toast and Android kills it.

```
[70053] vulnerable environment detected. The app will be closed.
```

I couldn't find anything on Google yet. Maybe some new security change introduced in Android 12.

Does anybody know how to solve this? Or what's causing this? Any leads would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with [AppSeal](https://www.appsealing.com/). We raised this to them and they fixed it in their new version.